# Two factor authentication for SSH

Tags: ssh

I am looking for a 2 factor authentication system that supports;

- Public Keys
- SFTP logins

Right now the options I know,

Authy: Allows you to use it with Public Key authentication but it fails SFTP logins for some reason. It says that it supports SCP etc. but SFTP connection try with Filezilla fails.

Google 2 Factor: Doesn't allow Public Key auth, probably has some bypass method for SFTP.

Duosecurity : Haven't tried yet.

I am on Debian system

Comment: Why don't you try duo ?

Comment: I will give it a try now, it is "free" for now (for simple usage) but you never know when will they make it paid. It would be a hassle to remove it, so I am a bit unsure about it

Comment: Free isn't a listed requirement. Sometimes paying for something is worthwhile.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but on-topic on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing a little with Google Authenticator. I don't have any issues using SFTP with two factor or public key on Linux command line. I have seen some strange behavior with GUI clients in Windows. I prompt for the OTP and password separately which requires Challenge Response to be enabled in sshd. You also need to watch out for SELinux on RHEL flavored Linuxes since the default location of the config file is not accessible by sshd. You can either modify the policy or move the file to .ssh for each user. If you want a more centralized solution you can consider RADIUS. That has the benefit of having fewer OTPs to deal with in your client. You could copy one key everywhere but that starts to defeats the idea of OTP without a central authority to keep track of key use.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do OTP authentication and SSH pub key auth?

Your bullet points are a bit misleading, because ssh pub key is an authentication mechanism and sftp is an application (or protocol).

You might also take a look at [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org), which is an OTP authentication backend for OTP tokens like the google authenticator, the yubikey and many other OTP devices.
I also started an implementation on "SSH token", to support ssh pub keys, but it is under development at the moment (see [github](https://github.com/privacyidea/privacyidea)). Do you have any input?

You would connect your SFTP via RADIUS protocol and could then use many different token types at the same time.